# Business Logic : influence on language to be use?

Tags: web-applications, business-logic

I have to develop a web application which has a complex business logic. I have to process lot of data and do lots of analysis to produce stats.
Currently I know of 3 language used for server side of web application :
1. python
2. php
3. java/spring/hibernate

because i have to start from scratch and also have to learn the language ( i don't know any of the three), therefore i want to know using which language (framework)it will be preferable to perform complex analysis and big data processing. 
I am also going for fast to develop, easy, library support etc.

P.S This question is not to proof which is better language?

Comment: There is nothing in your requirements that could make one of these a better match.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a completely subjective question and is **ultimately up to the business decision team wherever you work.**

My advice?  Take a look at the languages you are considering, see which one of them looks to be the easiest for **you** to learn and develop with if you're gonna be the one doing all/most of the work.  There are plenty of frameworks and documentation available about these languages.

Personally, I'm a PHP developer because it can scale from miniscule to Facebook-size and it was easy for me to pick up on.

Other people automatically think I'm a noob because of this.  But, I don't care I still produce websites.

Also, don't forget about Microsoft's ASP or ASP.net.